# I am having some trouble with web scraping using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-3.7

when ever i try to extract text between tags using .text() it gives a blank screen with just [] as output

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.amazon.in/s?k=ssd&ref=nb_sb_noss")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

product = soup.find_all("h2",class_="a-link-normal a-text-normal")
results = soup.find_all("span",class_="a-offscreen")

print(product)
```

this is the output that i got :

```
C:\Users\Kushal\Desktop\requests-tutorial>C:/Users/Kushal/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe c:/Users/Kushal/Desktop/requests-tutorial/scraper.py
[]
```

when i try listing everything with a for loop then, nothing shows up not even the empty square brackets

Comment: try print(soup.prettify()) - this shows the html that you can scrape. Your elements do not appear. Amazon have added code to prevent people scraping. You might have better luck with selenium (not tried scraping Amazon)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment below. I've modified the code to fetch all the product title on the said page along with the price details.

Mark as answer if it works, else comment for further analysis.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml


dataList = list()
headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5)",
    "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "accept-charset": "cp1254,ISO-8859-9,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip,deflate,sdch",
    "accept-language": "tr,tr-TR,en-US,en;q=0.8",
} 

url = requests.get('https://www.amazon.in/s?k=ssd&ref=nb_sb_noss'.format(), headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, 'lxml')

title = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class':'a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal'})
price = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class':'a-offscreen'})


for product in zip(title,price):
    title,price=product
    title_proper=title.text.strip()
    price_proper=price.text.strip()
    print(title_proper,'-',price_proper)
```

Comment: i am a noob in this subject can you please explain the headers that you have created

Comment: Every time a user visits a webpage. There is an exchange of information. We are mimicking those by stating if any header information is requested by the server then pass the message accordingly. [link] https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/http-headers/ there is a list of various type of handshakes that happen between the server and the browser thats highlighted well in this post.

Comment: so can i use any type of headers or the ones specific to my os

Comment: and froim where do i get these headers from

Comment: You can use the headers I've mentioned as-is. This should address most requirements. The link I shared as reference was more to understand what headers are and how websites communicate.

Comment: i have a problem where i am only getting the title of the first product when printing the title and not able to iterate through the remaining titles as it is raising Navigablestring exception ive tried to avoid this with exception handling but nothing shows up

Comment: @kushalr3ddy I've updated the code above and it works for me. Test it out and let me know.